# What is the $\log_{10}$ transformation of the Rayleigh distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, transformation

If one takes the Rayleigh distribution,
$$f(x; \sigma) = \frac{x}{\sigma^{2}} e^{-x^{2}/(2\sigma^{2})}$$
and makes a transformation into $\log_{10}$ units, i.e. $\log_{10}(x)$ what is the resultant distribution? Is this a known distribution -- what is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(Y \leq y) &= P(\log_{10}(X) \leq y)\\
&= P(X \leq 10^y)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Differentiating w.r.to $y$ 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f_Y(y) &= f_X(10^y) \frac{d}{dy}(10^y) \\
&= \frac{10^y}{\sigma^2} e^{-10^{2y}/2\sigma^2} 10^y (\ln 10) \\
&= \frac{10^{2y}}{\sigma^2} e^{-10^{2y}/2\sigma^2} (\ln 10) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I don't know if it belongs to any known distribution.

Comment: The function you give is perfect. I'll wait a little to see if anyone can name it..